# Linear Algebra, Hoffman and kunze exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Anyone could please help me out with questions $11$ and $14$? another one is $10$ that ask for show that if $I-AB$ is inversible $nxn$ matrixs then $I-BA$ is irreversible with $(I-BA)^{-1} = I + B(I-AB)^{-1}A$.

[Hofmman exercises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIks9.png)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. On this site it is mandatory to ask just one question at once. Also, homework questions that do not contain a substantial effort on behalf of the person that asks them tend to get closed before receiving an answer.

Comment: As @G.Sassatelli said, only ask one question at a time.  Also, not everyone has a copy of your textbook, so if you create new math.SE questions for Q 11 & 14, please copy them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Whenever when you know the inverse, all you need to do is multiply the two matrices and show that you get $I_n$.

$$(I-BA) (I + B(I-AB)^{-1}A)=??$$

**Hint 2**
$$(I-BA)(I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A)=I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A-BA-BAB(I-AB)^{-1}A \hspace{1cm} (*)$$

Now you see $AB(I-AB)^{-1}$ in your computation, and you know that
$$(I-AB)(I-AB)^{-1}=I$$

Therefore
$$(I-AB)^{-1}-AB(I-AB)^{-1}=I \Rightarrow \\
AB(I-AB)^{-1}=(I-AB)^{-1}-I$$

What happens when you replace this in $(*)$ ? ;)

Comment: i did it, but i dont how to get in I by  (I - BA - BAB(I-AB)^{-1}A)

Comment: @EduardoSilva Ok, show me what you got so far, and I will help you continue....

Comment: i aim to prove $(I-BA)(I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A) = I$ and $(I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A)(I-BA) = I$ and considered $ I = (I-AB)(I-AB)^{-1}$ but i just developed de product and this come  $$(I-AB)(I-AB)^{-1} - BIA - BAB(I-AB)^{-1}A = (I-AB)(I-AB)^{-1} - B(I-AB)(I-AB)^{-1}A - BAB(I-AB)^{-1}A$$
and now? there is something that a can evidence to get $I_{n}$?

Comment: @EduardoSilva check my edit....